# List<Object> into CharSequence[]

Tags: java

I have a this list:

```
public List <Book> bookList = new ArrayList <>();
```

You can get Book object's title (which is a CharSequence) using .title on the Book object reference.

And what I want to do is declare a method which would have List of Books as input parameter and return CharSequence[] containing book labels. 
bookList is sorted albhabeticaly, I would like to keep this if possible.

**Edit:** Title is CharSequence too.

Comment: Did you try something ?

Comment: Where's your attempt? ``String`` implements ``CharSequence``.

Comment: A list of requirements is not a question. Also, it is not clear what the structure of the char sequence is supposed to be. You should write a program that meets your requirements to the best of your ability, and then you can ask about difficulties you have in your program.

Comment: I tried writing some method, but it went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this for [`String.valueOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-java.lang.Object-):

```
public CharSequence[] toCharSequenceArray(List<?> objects) {
    return objects.stream().map(String::valueOf).toArray(CharSequence[]::new);
}
```

or this for `Book.title`:

```
public CharSequence[] toCharSequenceArray(List<Book> books) {
    return books.stream().map(b -> b.title).toArray(CharSequence[]::new);
}
```

The latter in Java7 (using an iterator):

```
CharSequence[] bookTitles = new CharSequence[books.size()];
int index = 0;
for (Book book : books) {
    bookTitles[index++] = book.title;
}
return bookTitles;
```

Or an old-style for-loop:

```
CharSequence[] bookTitles = new CharSequence[books.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < bookTitles.length; i++) {
    bookTitles[i] = books.get(i).title;
}
return bookTitles;
```

Comment: ``String::valueOf`` might include other data besides the title depending on what ``Book.toString`` does

Comment: @f1sh yes, he's changing the question all the time.

Comment: the first version of the question already states "You can get Book object's title (which is a String) using .title on the Book object reference."

Comment: I hate StackOverflow. Three correct answers, but no one can upvote the other answer because that would kill the own answer (which in turn each finds to be the most clever one).

Comment: Yup, that's how it is. Accept my upvote as a peace agreement.

Comment: I will accept one of the answer, but currently I am not on my machine. I am writing this on my mobile.

Comment: So this sollution works for me, but is there any other solution using Java SE 7?

Comment: @MatejDesign Sure, but that's very basic Java stuff.

Comment: Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
bookList.stream().map(b -> ((CharSequence)b.title)).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray();
```

or, like steffen does it in his answer, use the array collector at the end. In general, I would suggest to work with `List`s instead of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of `Book` objects, you can use Java 8's `stream` to stream through elements, `map` each element to corresponding title and `collect` it to an array, e.g.:

```
List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
CharSequence[] names = books.stream()
    .map(b -> (CharSequence)b.title)
    .toArray(CharSequence[]::new);
```